# Unable to trigger event from BaseObserver

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

**BaseObserver.php**

```
class BaseObserver {

    public function saving(Eloquent $model)
    {
        exit('BaseObserver');
    }
}
```

**ProductObserver.php**

```
class ProductObserver extends BaseObserver {

    public function saving(Eloquent $model)
    {
        exit('ProductObserver');
    }
}
```

**observers.php**

```
Product::observe(new ProductObserver);
```

In the scenario above, the BaseObserver saving event is never triggered, while the one from ProductObserver works fine.

Is there any special action I should take to make BaseObserver saving event trigger before the one from ProductObserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the parent's `saving` method from within the child's `saving` method:

```
public function saving(Eloquent $model)
{
    parent::saving($model);

    exit('ProductObserver');
}
```